# Display mini search form in template?

Tags: magento2, template

**Magento 2.3.3**

I want to display the mini search form `form.mini.phtml` in a template. In Magento 1 I did it like this:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml')->toHtml();
```

How would I do that in Magento 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')->setTemplate('Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

I hope this will help you..!